# SQLAlchemy error when adding parameter to string SQL query

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to compose a string SQL query using SQLALchemy 1.1.2. I followed the explanation from the docs about [using textual SQL](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html#using-textual-sql) but encountered a syntax error when I ran the following code:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import text

# Create a database connection called "connection"...

q = text('USE :name')
connection.execute(q, name='DATABASE_NAME')
```

Here's the error message:

```
"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use 
near ''DATABASE_NAME'' at line 1") [SQL: u'USE %s;'] [parameters: 
(u'DATABASE_NAME',)]
```

Since I'm using the named colon format and passing the parameters as arguments to `connection.execute` I can't figure out why this problem is arising. I'm using a MySQL server, but if I read the docs correctly the `text` method should be DB-agnostic.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: You cannot use a parameter with `USE`, just like you can't do `SELECT * FROM :table`. You'll have to string formatting, like `'USE %s' % 'DATABASE_NAME'`.

Comment: I didn't see anything about this in the docs - so you're saying that the `text` method can compose other types of queries but not USE or SELECT queries? EDIT: I tried it with a SELECT query, like in the docs, and got the same error.

Comment: No. What I'm saying is that parameters as used here do not work on table names, only literals. While you can do `SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE id > :my_id_param`, you cannot do `SELECT * FROM :my_table_name_param`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html#using-textual-sql) you need to use the bindparams like so:

```
q = text('USE :name')
q.bindparams(name="DATABASE_NAME")
connection.execute(q)
```

or like this:

```
q = text('USE :name')
q = q.bindparams(bindparam("name", String))

connection.execute(q, {"name": "DATABASE_NAME"})
```

This worked for me with no issues. **Edit: I was wrong, it didn't work.**

The problem is the bind params is going to auto wrap your value with a single quote. So what's happening is you get the final compiles statement (which is invalid syntax):

```
use 'DATABASE_NAME'
```

If you were to create the query: `"Select * from mytable where column_a=:name"`; this will work. Because it's wrapping the value with single quotes.

I would suggest for your use statement to do:

```
q = "USE {}".format("DATABASE_NAME")
```

Or something similar.

Comment: Strange. I'm still encountering the error. When I execute the first example, I get this: (sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError) A value is required for bind parameter 'name' [SQL: u'USE %s']

Are you also using v1.1.2?

Comment: @jason-heine, can you specify the documentation version, and link (from the anchor text “the documentation” in your answer, if you like).

Comment: @bignose I had used the link the OP provided. However, I have updated my answer to include this link as well. Thanks

Comment: @JonathanCox I updated my answer to include what is really happening.

Comment: @JasonHeine Isn't using string formatting to parameterize a SQL query a big security vulnerability? Thanks for following up and updating your answer btw.

Comment: @JonathanCox Yes, it can be a security vulnerability. I typically set the database name in the connection, or create the table using classes, and then set the schema there. so table = Table('table_name', MetaData(), Columns, schema='my_database')

Comment: @JasonHeine Understood. I wish the sqlalchemy docs were clearer about the insertion of extra quotation marks around the parameters - it would have saved me a lot of time.

Comment: @JonathanCox I'm right there with you! Good luck :)